# How to cut out a rectangle (i.e. set it transparent) in imagemagick?

Tags: imagemagick, transparency, alpha-transparency

I combine three files, the 2nd and 3rd having some transparent areas, into one and this works fine:

```
convert image1.png image2.png image3.png -flatten image_combined.png
```

In addition to combining those pictures, I would like to cut out a rectangle in the middle of *image1.png*, leaving that area transparent, but can't do it.
One (old) example I've found on a forum is:

```
convert image1.png -alpha set -region 40x30+15+5 -alpha transparent image2.png
```

When I try it (as-is, not even trying to mix it with my previously mentioned code), it doesn't work at all, outputting *image2.png* identical to *image1.png* (update: I'm using the ImageMagick v7)

Any help would be appreciated,

Michael

Comment: I'm not at a machine to test, but try `convert -background none ...`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @MarkSetchell, but unfortunately it doesn't work either.

Comment: Your version may have some effect; which version are you using V6 or V7

Comment: The version 7, @Bonzo

Comment: Still not at a computer, but if you just want the job done *"quick and dirty"*, you could draw rectangle in an unlikely colour and then make that transparent... `convert image.png -fill magenta -draw "rectangle 10,10 20,20" -transparent magenta result.png`

Comment: It might be quick and dirty, @MarkSetchell, but it works. I'll just have to make sure not use it "as-is" on pictures with plenty of pure magenta in them ;) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an alternate to Mark's answer. (His answer only works for ImageMagick 7).

Note that you cannot draw transparency. You can only flood fill some region to replace a color with transparency. But that is more complex.

So the simple answer is to create a black square in a white background and add that image as the alpha channel. The white will keep the image opaque and the black will show as transparent.

```
convert -size 100x100 xc:red red.png
```

[image]

```
convert red.png \
\( +clone -fill white -colorize 100 \
    -size 90x90 xc:black \
    -gravity center -composite \) \
-alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite \
result.png
```

The above is Unix syntax for ImageMagick 6. For Windows, remove the \ from the parentheses and change the end of line \ to ^.

For ImageMagick 7, replace `convert` with `magick`

If your input image already has transparency, then you would have to extract its alpha channel and combine it with the rectangle image. Then replace the alpha channel of the input with the new combined alpha channel.

Comment: Thank you very much @fmw42 for your detailed answer! It's really good to have another slightly different solution, as it allows me to learn a lot about how ImageMagick works.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why I can't find an easy way to do this, but the following should work for even magenta-coloured images:

```
magick  xc:red[100x100\!]  \( +clone -threshold 0  -draw "rectangle 10,10 90,90" \) -channel-fx '| gray=>alpha' result.png
```

[image]

---

That first part is no different from:

```
magick -size 100x100 xc:red ...
```

The part inside parentheses makes an alpha channel. It does that with `+clone` which makes a copy of the original image - crucially the same size but without needing to know the size so it works for any image size. The `-threshold 0` makes every pixel with brightness zero or more become white - so that means effectively **all** pixels become white. I then use `-draw "rectangle x0,y0 x1,y1"` to draw the *"hole"* you want to punch in the image. As the default draw colour is black, the nett result of everything inside the parentheses is that you will get a black rectangle on a white background. This becomes the alpha channel in the next step.

The part after the parentheses forces that alpha channel into the original, red image making it transparent where the alpha channel is black and opaque where the alpha channel is white.

---

I have no idea why the following doesn't work:

```
magick ... \( ... \) -compose copy-alpha -composite result.png
```

---

If you want to see the alpha channel saved as a file called `"alpha.png"`, you can use:

```
magick  xc:red[100x100\!]  \( +clone -threshold 0  -draw "rectangle 10,10 90,90" -write alpha.png \) -channel-fx '| gray=>alpha' result.png
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Mark! It is more complicated for an ImageMagick beginner like myself and for now your previous method works perfectly but I'll definitely give it a try and read the docs to be able to fully understand this code, as it would be great to have a magenta-proof solution. Not that it should be a big issue, but just to have clean code ;)

Comment: I have added some extra explanation to my answer. Hopefully you can become more confident with it.

Comment: That 's really helpful. Thanks again @MarkSetchell!